# select statements with SQL

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

Is it possible to use select * for only one table when using a join statement?

Let's say these are the following tables;

```
B
userID
username

A
userID
entry 
....just pretend there are more columns for the sake of this example
```

What is the correct way to look up the username from table B?

```
select B.username, * from A
LEFT JOIN B on B.userID = A.userID
where A.entry = "XXXXX"
```

Or do I have to list out everything I want to select such as:

```
select B.username, A.userID, A.entry from A
left Join.....
```

Comment: What happens when you try it? You'd have had an answer a lot faster than asking here, and you might learn something useful in the process. :)

Comment: Be sure to accept an answer for this question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [table name].* to select all fields from one of the tables. For example, to select all fields from table B use:

```
 SELECT B.*, username FROM A
 LEFT JOIN B on B.userID = A.userID
 WHERE A.entry = "XXXXX"
```

edit - selected column username from A

Comment: Thanks, yours worked. I had to add username and then it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT A.* FROM ...` where `A` is the table you want to select from.